# Accessing GPS location and speed from native layer on Oreo

Tags: android, android-ndk, gps, location

I'm building an Android native application and I'm accessing sensors like camera, accel and gyro using native layer APIs. The list of supported NDK APIs can be found  [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/).

However, there seems to be no way to access the GPS location and speed using NDK APIs. Is this possible? Could someone throw some light?

Thank you.